# How to show users of database with Erlang?

Tags: ejabberd, erl, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-saas

I can't query in internal database, with console

```
ejabberdctl debug


Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:10]

Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
(ejabberd@localhost)1>
```

Is it possible to display the registered users on the ejabberd server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can execute this command in the shell, for example:

```
$ ejabberdctl registered_users localhost
user1
user2
user3
user8
user9
```

Comment: ok tks, how i can migrate a posgrest or mysql by jquery easy and see data registerd.

Comment: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/databases/mysql/#migrating-data-from-internal-database-to-mysql

Comment: ok, but i can migrate to posgrest using it command ejd2sql:export(<<"localhost">>, sql).?